# How to say, "I've been living in America for 9 months" (and still am)?

Tags: grammar, translation, aspect

So I've been trying to say that a friend has lived in America for about 9 months, and is still currently living in America.

Would it be:
アメリカで９月間ぐらいに住んでいます。

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct form of 住む, but I don't think it would be 住んでいました since it is still currently taking place.

Comment: The question title makes it sound like you're looking for how to say "blank" in Japanese. Why not say `How to say "I've been living in America for 9 months?` and then adapt the answer as necessary?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I might just do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The construct is more or less correct, but there are a few grammatical errors in your proposal.

> アメリカで９月間ぐらいに住んでいます。

1. I believe 住む takes に for the location of residence.

> アメリカ**に**住んでいます。

2. 「９月間ぐらい」 should be 「9ヶ月間ぐらい」, and does not need to take any particles. Also note that the 「間」 may also be dropped here in less formal situations.

> 9ヶ月間ぐらいアメリカに住んでいます。

This should convey the idea that you have been living in the United States for 9 months, and still are.

Similarly,

> １年間ぐらい日本語を勉強しています。

Comment: 「9ヶ月くらい」「一年くらい」でもいいね・・・(「間」なしで・・)

Comment: @Shoko I didn't mean to imply that it was necessarily required, but that is a good point. Thanks!

Comment: @Shoko Also, if I may ask, is the 間 also optional before 前に as well?

Comment: You can edit your post to show that the 間 is optional (telling the OP that Xヶ月くらい/X年くらい is casually used). And, no you don't say 「[9ヶ月間]{きゅうかげつかん}[前]{まえ}」 or 「一年間前」. You'd say Xヶ月前・X年前(+に・から・まで etc.)... though you'd say X週**間**前! Don't ask me why :D

Comment: @Shoko I see. Thanks! I will do so accordingly.

Comment: I think the reason for the discrepancy is that 時間 and 週間 are counter words, i.e., in the same class as 分, ヶ月, 年, etc. The 間 that attaches to 分, ヶ月, and 年 seems different... I think it means like "during", and hence 間前 means no sense ("before during"?). Of course, I have no idea why 間 is embedded in some counter words and not in others :-).

Answer (score 3):

住む　is indeed the correct verb, but you have to structure your sentence differently to make it clear that you are still living there.
前から is basically what you are looking for.

9か月前からアメリカに住んでいます。

Comment: I think that should be 9**か**月.

Comment: アメリカ **に** 住んでいます would be more grammatically correct (`で` would be used in アメリカ**で**暮らしています)

Comment: @Earthliŋ it should be `９ヶ月`. It's pronounced `カ` but written as `ヶ`.

Comment: 「9か月」「9ヶ月」、どっちでも…。(「9箇月」「9ヵ月」なんてのも…)